# Partial formatting in Microsoft Word find and replace

Tags: microsoft-word, search, regex, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2011

I want to use Word's "Advanced Find and Replace" tool to find this string:

> *See, e.g.,*

And replace it with this:

> *See, e.g.*,

The difference between the two strings is that the second comma is not italicized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can use Word to search for an italicised string and replace it with a non-italicised one, but you can't replace it with a partially italicised string. So the following two-step workaround might be the only thing you can do short of using VBA:

1. Search for "See, e.g.," (Font: Italic) and replace all with "See, e.g.~~" (Font: Italic)
2. Search for "~~" (Font: Italic) and replace all with "," (Font: Not Italic)

Note: Of course you can use any unique string in place of "~~".